# Field permissions removed on upgrading to V31

Tags: custom-object, deployment, ide

I have upgraded my Force.com IDE to version 31.  This added the below permissions to my existing custom objects

```
 <enableBulkApi>true</enableBulkApi>
    <enableSharing>true</enableSharing>
    <enableStreamingApi>true</enableStreamingApi>
```

Now after committing when I deploy my code to a new org and login as System administrator the fields are not visible . I have to manually give the fields permission. 
This issue is occurring with existing objects.

Answer (score 0):

Add  System Admin, and any profile you wish to have the permissions passed, to the **Changeset** or **package.xml** before deploying. Its now possible to move Field Level Security  to  destination org.